# I am asking an advice on how to proceed on populating an html with python

Tags: python, html, css

So I have a txt file of a conversation with a format as such

name and date 
message

name and date
message

etc

and I have an html/CSS template ready and a python script that reads the txt

I want to take each name and date
message on txt and populate the html with them under the tag/class

for example

```
<ul class="chat">
 <li class="chat__bubble chat__bubble--rcvd chat__bubble--stop">name date and the message </li>
<li class="chat__bubble chat__bubble--rcvd chat__bubble--stop">name date and the message </li>
```

I do not want a code, but an advice or an example on how to approach it. any idea?

Comment: Best bet is to try a templating engine like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/intro/#basic-api-usage)

Comment: maybe use selenium and get the classnames from the li tags and store them into a list, and set them the text as classname.text = variable

Comment: Jinja2, offers exactly what I need, I will use it later to expand on this project. For now, I will stick to Chelsea's answer for simplicity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were me I would probably use the open('filename', 'r') and set each line of the contents into a list and then iterate over the list and write it to a certain start point in the css/html document. Also for the tags you could assign them to variables and use the write function .write(aTag + textfromchat + endTage) etc etc etc.

Comment: I like your advice due to simplicity. So I am going to give it a check =D

Comment: Mucho Gracias :)